# Call stored procedure that returns scalar value in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Using .Net Core and Entity Framework Core 5.0.7 I want to call a stored procedure that returns a scalar value.

As far as I understood to call a stored procedure it must returns an entity model.

Let's say I have a product table in SQL and stored procedure returns a set of products so we call it like

```
 var products = (await _dbContext.priducts.FromSqlRaw($"sp_GetProducts").ToListAsync())
```

But now I have another case which is returning only a scalar value.I read many articles and questions here in Stackoverflow so I came up with one working solution which is not good in my opinion.

I have created an entity model called `ScalarBool`

```
public partial class ScalarBool
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

and added it to my `dbcontext`

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ScalarBool>().HasNoKey();
```

We are using database-first approach. So other developers may do dbScaffold with force and that model will disappear because it's not actually a table in SQL Server.

Other solution I got which is not working is below

```
        SqlParameter orderId = new SqlParameter("@orderid",orderId);
        SqlParameter customerid = new SqlParameter("@customerid", customerId);
        SqlParameter isDelivered = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@Value",
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt,
            Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
        };

        await _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("[dbo].[is_delivered] @orderid , @customerid, @Value", orderId , customerid, isDelivered);
        var isDelivered = Convert.ToInt64(isDelivered.Value);
```

But I got this error

> 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlCommandAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ExecuteSqlCommandAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So what is the best solution here?

Comment: Add the nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational and add this on top of your class using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Comment: @viveknuna I tried installing package and add using but still same error is showing

Comment: The duplicates cover the second attempt (with output parameter). `ExecuteSqlCommand` was in EFC 1.x / 2.x, in 3.0 and later the method names are different. When passing `SqlParameter` objects, use `ExecuteSqlRaw`.

Answer (score 0):

Install:-

`MicrosoftEntityFramworkCore.Tools`

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

If not works then I will be recommended you install the NuGet package similar to your .net core version.like if your version .net core 3.1 then your NuGet should be 3.1/3.0/3.2 especially your `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` Nuget.then install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`

Hope it will resolve your issue.